# Polymer: how to do 'this.set' or 'notifyPath' on dinamically generated subproperties of JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, object, polymer-2.x

```js
var newUser = evt.detail.response[0];
var keys = Object.keys(evt.detail.response[0]);
var cpt = [];
keys.forEach(key => {
    if (this.storedUser[key] != newUser[key]) {
        this.storedUser[key] = newUser[key];
        cpt.push(key);
    }
});
```

How can I notify the change of this kind of variables?

Since I cannot do:

```
this.set('storedUser[key]', newUser[key]);
```

Nor:

```
this.set('storedUser'[key], newUser[key]);
```

Nor:

```
this.notifyPath('storedUser[key]');
```

Nor:

```
this.notifyPath('storedUser'[key]);
```

Comment: To be clear in our writing, [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: Thank you ! That's is insightful

Answer (score 0):

You can do (it's a string, so concat it before) :

```
const key = "storedUser."+key;
this.set(key, []);
```

from docs : https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/model-data
(same for 1.0)

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for me :(. Since it's was about updating the localStorage variable, I directly modified it :  
`var user = localStorage['user-storage'];  
user = JSON.parse(user); // Parse the stuff
//Do your cooking.
user = JSON.stringify(user); // Stringify and reaffect the variable.

localStorage['user-storage'] = user;`
(sorry I don't know how to break lines in comment (it says two spaces but it doesn't work)